# How do I make chromedriver compatible with google chrome for selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting this error: The chromedriver version (114.0.5735.90) detected in PATH at C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Python 3.11\chromedriver.exe might not be compatible with the detected chrome version (122.0.6261.129); currently, chromedriver 122.0.6261.128 is recommended for chrome 122.*, so it is advised to delete the driver in PATH and retry

I went on the chromedriver website and clicked on the link for versions higher than 115. Where do I go from here? I now have chromium downloaded but do I put in the Python file?

Comment: Anytime your running Chrome browser is updated, you need the matching Chrome Driver version https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Please try this webpage https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/ to download the current stable version (122.0.6261.128) and replace the older file.

The chromedriver web page (https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) contains a link to this new page containing new chrome driver versions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if chrome released an update for windows & mac (122.0.6261.129 https://chromereleases.googleblog.com/2024/03/stable-channel-update-for-desktop_12.html) but did not publish a corresponding driver https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/. However, selenium tries to use the .128 driver together with the .129 chrome release, which terminates chrome immediatly.